# Pymel OpenMaya dependency?

Tags: maya, autodesk, pymel, maya-api

Where can I get the Open dependency for pymel? I do not see anywhere in the docs where this is stated

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
 import pymel.core
 File "/Users/kromah/Documents/Developer/Github/pymel/pymel/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
import pymel.versions as _versions
File "/Users/kromah/Documents/Developer/Github/pymel/pymel/versions.py", line 13, in <module> from maya.OpenMaya import MGlobal as _MGlobal
```

**[ImportError: No module named OpenMaya]**

Comment: are you trying to run this inside maya or a mayapy session ?

Comment: in a mayapy session

Comment: It looks like you're running out of the github repo?  You don't need to do that if you just want to work with pymel -- it's included with maya so anywhere you can get a maya script console (in mayapy or the listener) you can just  `import pymel.core` and go